# How to print elements in an list which have the starting letter 'A'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print an elements in an list contains more than 100 names.. In those 100 names I want to print only the names which have the starting letter 'A'.. How can I do this in python??

Comment: Combine the duplicate I linked to with `startswith('A')`

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Iam new to programming as well as python. I just started to learn programming in stack overflow.. Could you help me out from the above question I asked?

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = ['apple', 'Alexander', 'Ball', 'Alphabet']
>>> a_list = [element for element in my_list if element.startswith('A')]
>>> a_list
['Alexander', 'Alphabet']
```

**Alternatively**, more Pythonic way to achieve this is by using `itertools.ifilter()`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_list = ['apple', 'Alexander', 'Ball', 'Alphabet']
>>> list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.startswith('A'), my_list))
['Alexander', 'Alphabet']
```